# Swift Collection Of Objects Conforming To Protocol With Associatedtype

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, type-erasure, swift4

I have a question (maybe regarding type erasure). Imagine the following scenario:

```
public protocol DataItem {

    associatedtype T
    var action: ((_ item: T) -> Void)? {get}
}

struct UserItem: DataItem {

    typealias T = UserItem

    // Custom Properties
    let name: String

    // Protocol: DataItem
    let action: ((T) -> Void)?
}

struct DriverItem: DataItem {

    typealias T = DriverItem

    // Custom Properties
    let licenseNumber: String

    // Protocol: DataItem
    let action: ((T) -> Void)?
}

let items = [
    UserItem(name: "Dexter", action: { (item) in print(item.name)}),
    DriverItem(licenseNumber: "1234567890", action: { (item) in print(item.licenseNumber)})
]

items.forEach {
    $0.action?($0)
}
```

I have a DataItem which is an abstract data item for a UITableViewCell and which has an action property that should be called when the cell is selected. My question is how can I create an array of DataItem objects, select an item from this list (or iterate over it) and call the respective action, that will print the name of the UserItem and the license number of the DriverItem. But with that implementation above the compiler complains with the following message that the items list can only be of type [Any]...

`Heterogeneous collection literal could only be inferred to '[Any]'; add explicit type annotation if this is intentional`

That way I cannot call the action declared in the protocol DataItem. I tried to wrap my head around type erasures but couldn't understand it yet...

Would be happy if anyone comes up with a solution...

Comment: It looks somewhat weird that you `associatedtype` in `UserItem`(/`DriverItem/) is `UserItem`(/`DriverItem/) itself meaning that the _instance_ closure `action` takes a single argument of the same type as the instance that owns it. Is this as intended, that e.g. a given `UserItem` instance is to perform an action on _another_ instance of `UserItem`? I would expect the action to be performed upon the instance itself rather than a secondary external instance, but maybe this is an intended design choice. Anyway, if so, you could loose the `associatedtype` and just use `Self` instead of `T`.

Comment: It is intended like with target/action in UIControls to provide the sender in the action method. And the sender is the item itself. I want it that way that it is possible to use functionality of the concrete type (like name and licenseNumber) in the action method - you know? The important thing is that the items only live inside a DataSource object that has no idea about the concrete types. That's why I cannot access concrete-type functionality directly. I'll try your approach asap. Thanks a lot for that :-)

Comment: Arg.... using Self instead of T behaves the same: `Protocol 'DataItem' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`. Due to this behaviour type eraser are written. But I don't understand how to do it correctly... anybody an idea?

Answer (score -1):

It's not that hard with no additional requirements:

```
struct UserItem {
    let name: String

    func action() {
        print(name)
    }
}

struct DriverItem {
    let licenseNumber: String

    func action() {
        print(licenseNumber)
    }
}

let data = UserItem(name: "Test")
let closure = { print("Some object data \(data.name)") }
let items = [
    UserItem(name: "Dexter").action,
    DriverItem(licenseNumber: "1234567890").action,
    closure
]

items.forEach {
    $0()
}
```

Comment: the action closure is considered to be a CLOSURE that can be set from outside not a static function.

Comment: You can put any closure with the right signature into the array - you just can't have closures that take different parameters. You can also put a struct with a title (example) and a void-closure in an appropriate array.

Answer (score -1):

The error just asks you to add a type to items:

```
let items: Array<Any> = [
    UserItem(name: "Dexter", action: { (item) in print(item.name)}),
    DriverItem(licenseNumber: "1234567890", action: { (item) in print(item.licenseNumber)})
]
```

Not sure if this won't lead to more errors because I am not sure if you can call a completion block while creating the array.

---

**Edit**

I think what you are trying to do is get a call when the variable is called. The way to do this would be to use the `get` you already typed but didnt complete, like so:

```
var licenseNumber: String {
    get {
        print("doSomething!")
        return self.licenseNumber
    }
}
```

The array would become something like:

```
let items: Array<Any> = [
    UserItem(name: "Dexter"),
    DriverItem(licenseNumber: "1234567890")
]
```

Comment: It is still not possible to call the action method like `items.forEach {
    $0.action?($0)
}` since items contains Any objecs in your case. I suppose the type eraser pattern is what I search but I'm not sure how to implement this correctly.

Comment: @blackjacx I would do that with `if let item = $0 as? UserItem { item.action(item) }` instead of wasting a lot of time trying to work around it